# Recursively Joining Lists of Intervals based on endpoints

Tags: algorithm, jodatime, intervals

I have three intervals:

10:00AM - 11:00AM

11:00AM - 11:30AM

and 3:00PM - 3:30PM

I have written this algorithm to recursively condense and combine the intervals if they overlap or share endpoints.

```
 public boolean optimizeIntervals(ArrayList<Interval> list) {
    ArrayList<Interval> listToOptimize = list;
    ArrayList<Interval> optimizedList = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    for (int i = 1; i < listToOptimize.size(); i++) {
        if (listToOptimize.get(i).getStart().equals(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getEnd())) {
            optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
        }else{
            optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
        }
    }
    if(optimizedList.size() == listToOptimize.size()){
        setMeetingDuringIntervals(optimizedList);
        return true;
    }else{
        optimizeIntervals(optimizedList);
    }

    return false;
}
```

However following the stacktrace with the debugger I notice that when the size of the list is `2` after the first recursive call, I lose my final `Interval` of 3:00PM - 3:30PM

How can I rewrite that algorithm to not lose my final values?\

Here's what I mean for my issue:

RUN 1

JOIN INTERVALS 1 AND 2

Creates 10:00 AM - 11:30 AM

DO NOTHING WITH 3:00PM - 3:30PM

Recursive Call

Checks to see if 3:00-3:30PM has any overlap with interval 1?

No

Only adds 3:00-3:30PM

Logic of my code:

If `i`'s `start time` matches `i-1`'s `end time`. Add them to the optimization list.

If not,

add just `i` to the optimization list.

However at this current solution the algorithm messes up on the second run through with `i` starting at `1`, and only adding 3:00 - 3:30 PM and not the first interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed my issue with this algorithm:

```
  public boolean optimizeIntervals(ArrayList<Interval> list) {
    ArrayList<Interval> listToOptimize = list;
    ArrayList<Interval> optimizedList = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    for (int i = 1; i < listToOptimize.size(); i++) {
        if(listToOptimize.size()==2){
            if (listToOptimize.get(i).getStart().equals(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getEnd())) {
                optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
            }else if(listToOptimize.get(i).getStart().isAfter(listToOptimize.get(i-1).getEnd())){
                optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
                optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i-1).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i-1).getEnd()));
            }
        }
        else{
             if (listToOptimize.get(i).getStart().equals(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getEnd())) {
                optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
            } else if (listToOptimize.get(i).getStart().isAfter(listToOptimize.get(i - 1).getEnd())) {
                optimizedList.add(new Interval(listToOptimize.get(i).getStart(), listToOptimize.get(i).getEnd()));
            }
        }
    }
    if(optimizedList.size() == listToOptimize.size()){
        setMeetingDuringIntervals(optimizedList);
        return true;
    }else{
        optimizeIntervals(optimizedList);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Handling the case if there is a final join (meaning that the list size is 2);

I don't know if there is a better way to handle that but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compress(list) {
  if(list.length < 2) { return list; }
  // sort your interval list by the first value
  var sortedList = list.sort(function(a, b) { return a[0] - b[0]; });
  // compress your list into an result set
  var result = [sortedList[0]];
  var working = result[0];
  for(var i = 1; i < sortedList.length; i++) {
    var current = sortedList[i];
    // does the first value overlap the range?
    if(current[0] >= working[0] && current[0] <= working[1]) {
      // update the second value of the range
      working[1] = Math.max(current[1], working[1]);
    } else {
      // add a new unique range
      result.push(current);
      working = result[result.length - 1];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var intervals = [[1,3], [3,5], [6,10], [11,13], [13,14]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(compress(intervals)));
```